# Finding the roots of an equation with variable powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I have the following equation in a single variable $r$, as below:

$$\frac{(4^{1 + \epsilon} \epsilon^2 r^2 - 
  2^{2 + \epsilon} (2 + \epsilon(2 + \epsilon)) r^{3 + \epsilon} + (2 + \epsilon)^2 r^{4 + 2 \epsilon})}{(2^{1 + \epsilon} \epsilon + (2 + \epsilon) r^{1 + \epsilon})^2} + a^2  = 0$$

Here, $a,\epsilon$ are constants. The parameter $\epsilon$ is "small" where $0<a,\epsilon<1$ and as $\epsilon \to 0$, the equation reduces to a quadratic,

$$r^2 - 2r + a^2 = 0 $$

whose roots are trivial. By choosing a value of $\epsilon$ I get roots which are quite close to the limiting case of $\epsilon \to 0$ (which is easy to see since the equation continues to be "almost quadratic"), but I am interested in general roots, as a function of $\epsilon$.

I tried to do a brute force simplification and then take a transformation of the form $y = r^2$ to see if I could reduce it to a quadratic including $\epsilon$ but that didn't get me anywhere. Is there any other way to proceed?

Comment: You are trying to solve $$ (2 + \epsilon)^2 r^{4 + 2 \epsilon} - 
  2^{2 + \epsilon} (2 + 2\epsilon + \epsilon^2) r^{3 + \epsilon}+(2 + \epsilon)^2a^2 r^{2 + 2\epsilon}+2^{2 + 2\epsilon} \epsilon^2 r^2  +2^{2 + \epsilon} \epsilon(2 + \epsilon)a^2 r^{1 + \epsilon}+ 2^{2 + 2\epsilon} \epsilon^2a^2 = 0$$for $r$.

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw I want to find the roots of the equation I have written down, in terms of $a,\epsilon$.

Comment: That seems impossible for general $a,\epsilon$ as the equation is so bulky.

Comment: If $r$ is a real solution, then the numerator of the fraction has to be negative, and so every real solution $r$ has to satisfy $2\bigg(\dfrac{\epsilon}{2+\epsilon}\bigg)^{2/(1+\epsilon)}\lt r\lt 2$.

Comment: Why do you expect that one could have a closed-form formula for $r$ in terms of $a$ and $\epsilon$? Can you please say a bit more about where this equation is from?